# Cassandra Moving Data to Another New Cassandra node -

Tags: cassandra

I have one production cassandra node and would like create same cassandra in my local machine. As per my understanding, I can opt following option

```
 1. Taking snapshot of each keyspace from production and use it in local machine.(But It would take more time as I have many keyspace).
 2. Exporting production cassandra data to as CSV and importing in to local cassandra(I have COUNTER TABLE. Hence,It also creating some headache - Correct me if it is not).
```

My Question is "What will happen if I move entire data_directory,Commit_log folder from production to local and start local cassandra?". Is it possible anyway?

When I did the above solution,cassandra throws many errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is recreate your production node on a local machine, then all you really need to do is copy everything (assuming hardware is similar).

**From Production:**

- Flush the data from memtables to disk.
- Run nodetool snapshot and get snapshots for all your ColumnFamilies/KeySpaces
- Make sure you have the CQL scripts that created your ColumnFamilies/Keyspaces
- Copy the config files, commitlogs, saved_cache, logs, data directories

**To your local machine (assuming fresh install)**

- Install Cassandra (Make sure it's the same version as Production)
- Recreate ColumnFamilies/Keyspaces using the scripts you copied from production
- Copy over config files/edit your config files/saved_cache,logs, data directories
- Place snapshots in the proper directories

  - possibly something like `<data_dir>/<keyspace>/<columnfamily>/`
- Start up Cassandra

*Note: These checklists are not completely thorough*

Running nodetool repair isn't a bad idea in this case. Assuming you just want to recreate the production node on a local machine (as stated in the question), then it might be moot as the snapshot would have the current data.  Also running nodetool cleanup wouldn't hurt either, if repair was deemed essential.

**Answering your question:**

If you just copy the data directory and commitlogs from production onto your local machine won't really work as you need to recreate the keyspaces and column families to put the data in.  If however you did that, then something else is at work.  To get the data from one cassandra environment to the next, the config files, data directory (commitlogs, data, saved_cache, etc), and the schema scripts are the most important.  From there you probably can debug issues.  A fresh install (or remapping the current data/commitlog/etc directories to new directories, ie. new_data, new_commitlog, new_saved_cache) might be the easiest way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Hi.... that really nice... I confirmed that your direction is succeed  and I have made my local machine as a copy of production server. I believe, Your suggestion surely help others too..

Comment: Hello! I'm glad it helped.  Have fun with Cassandra!

Answer (score 1):

If you have one node, you can copy the /data, /saved_caches, and /commitlog folders to your local machine.You need the same version of cassandra. But first, you need to export your schema(s) from production and import into your local machine. Then stop local cassandra, delete any contents of local /commitlog folder, copy data from prod into local - the foldernames in /data will probably be different because newer versions of c* append a UUID to the tablename folders. but it will work. you may have to run `nodetool repair` afterward.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs and it  give me some insights.

Comment: I would think that you should also stop the production node if you just want to copy files... otherwise it's going to change as you run your backup.